# Select all rows where all cells equal one another

Tags: excel, select, conditional-statements

I have a large table that only shows a single type of information: whether or not a species of plant was present at a particular study site.  I have 500+ species listed in the first column, and 30 sites as column names.  The table is populated with a simple "Y" or "N" to show presence.  Example:

```
Scientific Name         Old Wives Beach    Dadi      Orote N Airstrip
Abelmoschus moschatus   N                  N         N
Abrus precatorius       Y                  N         Y
Abutilon indicum        N                  N         N
```

However, the species list contains some species that do not occur at any sites, rendering a row full of "N"s, like the 1st and 3rd rows in the example above.  I need to delete those rows in order to make the table more manageable.

Is there any way to achieve this without a long IF AND statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by pnuts' comment, in a new column, use the a [`COUNTIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) formula.  For example, `=COUNTIF(B2:AE2,"Y")`, assuming the row/column headers are in row 1 and column A and the data is in the range B2:AE501+.

If you then select the entire range, including the headers and the new formula column and add filters, then you can select only the rows where the count of Y's is 0.  Once you have only the 0's showing, you can select the entire rows and delete them (using Right-Click, Delete) without effecting the non-zero rows.

At this point, if you no longer need the count column, you can turn off the filter and delete the column but I wouldn't be surprised if you find the count comes in handy for some other reason.

Alternately, you could just use the filter to HIDE the 0 rows rather than delete them and that way to don't remove the data altogether but it's no longer in your way.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is one way to do this, assuming there are no gaps in the data.  The animated gif steps through to demonstrate how it works.  You should remove the .select statements once you understand it.

[image]

```
Sub deleteIfAllN()
Dim plantR As Range, cell As Range, allN As Boolean
Set plantR = Range("A2")
While plantR <> ""
  plantR.Select
  Set r = plantR.Offset(0, 1)
  allN = True
  Do
    r.Select
    If r <> "N" Then
      allN = False
      Exit Do
    End If
    Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)
  Loop Until r = ""
    Set plantR = plantR.Offset(1, 0)
    Rows(plantR.row - 1).Select
    If allN Then Rows(plantR.row - 1).Delete
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Advanced Filter`

Set up your data and criterion area as below

For the example you posted, the formula would be:

```
=COUNTIF($B8:$D8,"N")<>3
```

For 30 columns, just modify the range and the count.

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

I chose to filter in place

Note that there is also an option to `Copy to another location` which would place the results of the filter in another location.